# Content pushing down and up with fixed bg issue

Tags: css, html, sass

I'm needing a fixed full size background in a section that is below the navbar. When I get down to mobile, and toggle my navigation, it pushes the section down including the image - but once fully expanded it will go back up while the content stays where it is meant to.

If I change the background from fixed then my content will be too long for the image's height and this is not what I'm after.

Can anyone offer a solution?

I've included a codepen below - please note this is just a snippet to provide an example.

(need to provide code to link codepen)

```
.contact__full-bg-container {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    ...
}
```

http://codepen.io/jreynolds90/pen/BLqZvj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some css to `.nav--lower`. Try adding:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: thanks @VictorLuna i'll add this, was there anyway to do this with keep the content AND bg img being pushed down and the nav not over laying the background??